# What is nesting/ what is a nesting vector in energy contour plots?

Tags: condensed-matter, tight-binding

I am making different plots for a 2-d non-interacting tight binding Hamiltonian 
$$ H  = - t \sum_{<ij>, \sigma} c_{i \sigma}^{\dagger} c_{j \sigma} + h.c$$

I get the dispersion relation $$\epsilon (k) = -2 t ( \cos(k_{x} a) + \cos (k_{y} a))$$

Plotting the contours of this, I get many k values giving me the same energy $\epsilon = 0$, that contour looks like a rhombus. I know that this has something to do with nesting but I don't understand exactly what is it.

[image: Contours of energy in Brillouin Zone]

I'll appreciate referring to good sources on this too. I can't seem to find any that explains this clearly without referring to other things I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Nesting" refers to a Fermi surface where two points on the Fermi surface are connected by half a reciprocal lattice vector. When this occurres, it usually indicates the system is critical or unstable with respect to an interaction.

If your think about adding an interaction term to the Hamilton via perturbation theory, you'll find that any translationally invariant term only couples states with the same momentum, up to a reciprocal lattice vector. If there's no nesting, the states will have very different energies, and thus be suppressed in perturbation theory. However, if the Fermi surface has nesting, there exists states with the same crystal momentum and same energy, which diverge in perturbation theory.

Comment: I've seen that one consequence of nesting is dimerization of lattice. Are there other consequences?

Comment: Doesn't that just mean that perturbation theory there is ill-defined and one needs degenerate perturbation theory?

Comment: Alright. So in that case, the reciprocal lattice vector is the one connecting the sides of the rhombus.
- So can I say there are two nesting vectors? One connecting each two opposite sides?
-How will I calculate that vector? Or do I just get it from the plot?
-So what does it mean that the system is unstable with respect to the interaction, I think this related to Michael's question. What if we use degenerate perturbation theory then, would there be no effect to nesting?

Comment: @Hoda Depending on which sides you try to connect, you'll find a nesting vector of $(\pm\pi,\pm\pi)$, with the signs depending on which sides you connect up. But these vectors are the same up to a reciprocal lattice vector, so there's really only one nesting vector.

Comment: @Hoda will maybe try to think about what happens in degenerate perturbation theory and expand, but if I remember correctly this instability is there regardless of what basis you use. It's really saying the Fermi surface is unstable to perturbations, not that you need to use a different basis. If you want the details, I believe they are in Ch 3 of Fradkin.